# Inline fancybox form - display:none wrapper is preventing the submit handler from firing

Tags: jquery, forms, fancybox

I am trying to get fancybox forms working using the inline route and I am having problems getting the submit handler to fire.

This is failing to work even when I use the form example lifted directly from the fancy box site Example 5 off http://fancybox.net/blog

Here is my code and it appears to be the `display:none` that is preventing the submit handler from working. I've been kicking this around for hours and am stumped.

Here is some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tip5").fancybox({
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'onClosed'      : function() {
            $("#login_error").hide();
        }
    });

    $("#login_form").bind("submit", function() {

        alert("THIS ALERT IS NOT FIRING");

        return false;
    });

}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="display:none">
    <form id="login_form" method="post" action="">
            <p id="login_error">Please, enter data</p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_name">Login: </label>
            <input type="text" id="login_name" name="login_name" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="login_pass">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" id="login_pass" name="login_pass" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <em>Leave empty so see resizing</em>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<a id="tip5" href="#login_form" title="Login">Try now</a>
```

The alert works when the display:none is removed.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: that code works for me.could you provide a link with an example of your issue?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check - much appreciated! I was linking to version 1.2.1 that I had uploaded a while back and using the code from the current site to test it but having updated to 1.3.4 it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You use probably the new fancybox the version number 2, try with the older version.
Some function have changed, per example `resize()` doesn't exist anymore, is it called `update()` now